# Omniauth-facebook gem response error handle issue

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth-facebook

I am developing `Rails 4 application` where i have to integrate `facebook sign up and login` using `omniauth-facebook gem`.

I done it successfully except 1 issue. Issue is when i login through facebook then successfully login into my site. In new tab i open facebook where i already logged in.

Now  i `logout` from my site. Its redirect to `login` screen in my site. Do nothing and just logout from facebook.

Now i try to login again using facebook log in button in my site. Where i got error.

```
OAuth2::Error
: {"error":{"message":"Code was invalid or expired. ","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

This error because of we logout from facebook and now try to login again from site. But code was expire so this error generate.

If i refresh my site then try to login through facebook then its work fine.

Now what is solutions or how to handle this error.

Thanks